# Получить индекс массива структур

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос, есть например такая структура

```
public static class Room{
  public int id;
  public String name;
  public String title;
  public int seats;
  public int base_id;
}
Room[][] room = ... // инициализация 8х7
```

Как найти индекс (x) `room[3][x]` при котором например `base_id = 3`?
Какие есть действенные методы кроме перебора всего массива в цикле?

Comment: А массив room[N] отсортирован по base_id?

Comment: нет, данные записаны в обычном порядке
так и должно быть

Comment: Как вы себе представляете поиск элемента в таком массиве без перебора?  Если только позвать экстрасенсов.

Comment: Может вам проще использовать `MapHash` вместо массива, в качестве  ключа использовать `base_id`.

Comment: а как в maphash прикрутить структуру?

Comment: @ромакосяченко, в `HashMap` в качестве значения может любой объект лежать.